# Google chrome truncating blog site

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hugo, blogdown

I have a static webpage created through R's blogdown and Hugo.It's working fine, mostly, except for some very peculiar behaviour on Chrome (but not iPhone chrome, or any other browser I've tried [firefox, safari]).

you can see the culprit here:
https://drmowinckels.io/blog/gamm-random-effects/

Depending on your browser size, and zoom level, you may or may not notice a boundary at some point on the page, and then the content of the page seems blank after this, until the disqus at the bottom appears. (this was first picked up on an android)

The content is still there, I can search the text, but you just can't see it. It is particularly obvious on my android chrome, where this happens far up on the page. Also, if one tried zooming in, the boundary moves, truncating *more* of the page's content.

I have tried using Chrome's devtools on my laptop, but I have no errors ofor the site, and I can't spot where this behaviour would come from. Using devtools, I recommend trying a 150% zoom on almost any device, to see the behaviour.

I have currently disabled handheld/mobile adaptations to my page, to help me debug, but I am at a loss right now.

**The question is: can anyone spot where this boundary truncating/hiding the post content is coming from?**

Any help/tips towards what may be doing this is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is your question, again? Please edit your "question"/post on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: sorry for not being more clear. I've update the post with a clearer question.

Comment: Start by fixing at least the structural issue of the stray end `</div>` tag, https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fdrmowinckels.io%2Fblog%2Fgamm-random-effects%2F

Comment: thanks for that link @CBroe! I fixed the stray <div> without help, but I think maybe it's the fading js that is tripping something up.

Comment: I found the culprit! It was a stupid fade-in issue (actually Steph Locke found it). But thank you for tips to sites that help figure out issues! They are bookmarked!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a double "fade-in" effect. Where a parent div was faded at the same time as a child div. So the child di malfunctioned with its fading. I removed the fading in the child-div and the issue was solved.

Thank you for links and helps to spot the issue!